# What is the correct way of keeping a Task alive and all Subscriptions active without spinning?

Tags: multithreading, task, task-parallel-library, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have the following TPL Task

```
public abstract class AggregatorBase : IAggregator
{

    public void Start(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(x =>
        {
            Aggregate(token);
        },TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, token);

        parent.Wait();
    }

    public abstract void Aggregate(CancellationToken ct);
}
```

within the Aggregate method implementations I have a number of Observable.Subscription's ending with the following

```
   public override void Aggregate(CancellationToken ct)
   {
            this.observables.Subscribe(// Do stuff);
            this.observables.Subscribe(// Do more stuff);

            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            }
   }
```

Question is whats the best way of keeping the Task alive and all Subscriptions active without spinning?

Comment: I'm confused - why are you blocking or sleeping at all if you're using Rx

Comment: I think he means he starts a task, that task sets up the Rx subscriptions, but then he doesn't want that task to continue on and 'complete'. So he's not blocking within the subscription callbacks themselves, but within the task that sets up the subscriptions.

Comment: @Tyson, but why? I agree with Paul Betts. It seems like a misuse/misunderstanding of Rx to me

Comment: @Lee It could be a misunderstanding. Or it could be part of the design of his architecture (e.g. The Task represents an active set of Rx subscriptions - once the Task completes or is cancelled, the internal observer(s) are unsubscribed). Without seeing the code in full it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @Tyson that was my objective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wait on the cancellation token's wait handle:

```
while ( !token.IsCancellationRequested )
{
    if ( token.WaitHandle.WaitOne( timeout ) )
    {
        // cancelled. Don't have to do anything here, the above while 
        // loop will break now.
    }
    else
    {
        // ''timeout' period elapsed - do some periodic work here.
    }

}
```

EDIT:
if you don't have any periodic work to do on this thread, then simply use the `WaitOne` overload without a timeout parameter.

```
token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

that will wait indefinetly until the cancellation token is signalled, then continue.

EDIT2:

I just read that you said you had that while loop within the observable's subscriptions. It should be just after you have setup all your observables subscriptions, but not within each actual subscription callback (those subscriptions will run on whatever thread invoked the source event(s) or possibly other thread pool threads, not the task thread that setup the subscriptions).

Comment: Can you see any issues with adding the token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(); just after the call to the Aggregate(token) but within the Task action delegate?